# not able to upload file in windows 8 tablet

Tags: javascript, cordova, windows-phone-8

I am using cordova 3.4.0 to transfer file from Windows 8 tablet to server here is my code

```
        var options  = new FileUploadOptions();
        options.fileKey     = "file";                
        options.chunkedMode = true; 
        options.headers = { Connection: "close" };
        options.params      = params;
        options.fileName    = "myimage.jpeg";
        options.httpMethod = "POST";

        options.mimeType    = "image/jpeg"; 

        var ft = new FileTransfer();
        ft.upload(imagePath, encodeURI("http://192.100.200.1/Files/upload.php"), win, fail, options);
```

but when the media transfer starts its  showing me following error

> Exception calling native with command :: FileTransfer :: upload
>   ::exception=WinRTError: The parameter is incorrect.

the same code is working properly in android and iOS.

Answer (score 0):

I found out, that with the `windows` platform the local `path`, in your case `imagePath`, needs to in a form like `ms-appdata:///` which can be obtained by using

```
var imagePath = fileEntry.toURL()
```

instead of using

```
fileEntry.toInternalURL()
```

which returns something like `cdvfile://` or instead of

```
fileEntry.fullPath
```

which returns something like `\\path\to\file`. It has to be noted, that according to the current docs of Cordova `4.0.0`, `cdvfile://` should be passed to `FileTransfer`. The windows platform of Cordova just is not there yet and needs to be updated.